# Order confirmation email not sending to guest user's email address Magento 2.3.5 -p1 community?

Tags: magento2, magento-community, magento2.3.5-p1

Order confirmation email to the guest user not sending but sending to logged-in customer. I am using the Magaplaza SMTP module for sending emails. Can anyone tell me Why this is happening?. I am searching for a solution for this for the last 2-3 days but not find any solution, why this happening, and how to fix it.
I am using Magento 2.3.5 -p1 community version and digital ocean server.

Comment: I just disable asynchronous sending, and now it working fine(sending mail to the guest user).

Answer (score 0):

The first, make sure all configuration is correct.

If configs are correct, so the cause is Magaplaza SMTP.
Sometimes, The Magaplaza SMTP extension will not send emails.
I have also encountered that error.

Comment: The rest of all transaction email is sending only not sending to the guest email.